# Why copy constructor changed previous object pointer member

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Date.h"
#include "Employee.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::to_string;

class TestOps {
public:
    int sex = 1;
    string toString() {
        return " sex:" + to_string(sex) ;
    }
};
class Test {
public:
    TestOps* testOps;
    Test(const Test& t) :Test{} {
        this->testOps = new TestOps{ *(t.testOps) };
    };
    Test()  {
        TestOps ops;
        //this->testOps = new TestOps{}; // it will be ok with this way
        this->testOps = &ops;
    }
};

int main() {
    // code not understand
    Test t1;
    cout <<"first testOps:" << t1.testOps->toString() << endl; // sex: 1
    Test t2{ t1 };
    cout << "first testOps:" << t1.testOps->toString() << endl; // sex: -858893460 ???? why?
    cout << "second testOps:" << t2.testOps->toString() << endl; // sex:  -858893460 ???? why?

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, why the first log is as expected while the later logs are not?

Also, `t1.testOps` address is different from `t2.testOps` which is as expected.

I have done some research but didn't find the answer. Maybe because I'm pretty new to cpp.

Comment: `ops` dies by the end of `Test` constructor, any access to it results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.  `this->testOps = &ops;` sets `tesOps` to point to an object that will be destroyed as soon as the constructor ends.

Comment: Storing a pointer you acquire with `&` for later use is (almost)  always a bad idea.

Comment: *I have done some research but didn't find the answer* -- What research have you done?  Storing the address of a local variable, and then attempting to access that address after that variable has gone out-of-scope, is fundamental C++ knowledge.  If you're learning C++ by using google or some videos, well, that isn't going to work out too well for such a difficult language.

Comment: @molbdnilo On the contrary: in modern, high-level C++ the *vast majority* of raw pointers that you store will point to objects with automatic storage, and will therefore be obtained via the `&` operator.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think molbdnilo was talking about storing pointers of objects passed by reference (&), not storing pointers of objects by using the address-of operator.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So, why is the first log working as I expected?

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior. Where the answers don't matter, and literally anything can happen.

Comment: @eike I doubt it, since the context is OP's question in which the `&` operator is used. But it actually makes no difference for my argument: both happen.

Comment: @xianshenglu Undefined Behaviour is undefined. It may work as expected, it may print constant garbage, it may print random garbage, it may format your hard drive or make [demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). There's just nothing you can predict about it.

Comment: Also worth noting that `Test` fails the Rule of 3/5.

Comment: @xianshenglu What *might* be happening is the memory previously occupied by `TestOps ops;` just randomly happens to not have been reused before the first output, but gets overwritten sometime before the later outputs.

Comment: @xianshenglu *So, why is the first log working as I expected?* -- Looking at your profile, you have used languages where behavior is well-predicted.  For example, if you go out-of-bounds of an array in Java, you get an exception thrown automatically.  C++ and C are different -- you make a mistake similar to that, and you may get no warning -- the program may even "work", or it may crash, or it may work on some days and not others, or some machines and not others, etc.  That is called *undefined behavior*, and it exists in C++.